# Proving a set is convex

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I am trying to prove that a set, $A$ of $\mathbb R^2$ with $x + y <10$, is convex. These are the steps I have gone so far:

Let says $(a, b) \in A$ and $(c, d) \in A$. Then I need to prove that for any numbers $m$ and $n$, $m+n = 1$:

$$\begin{align}
n(a,b) + (1-n)(c,d) &<10\\
\big((na + (1-n)c), (nb+(1-n)d) \big) &<10.
\end{align}$$

I first observe that $a+b < 10$ and $c+d<10$. Since $0 \leq n \leq 1$ and $0 \leq (1-n) \leq 1$, therefore

$$\begin{align}
n(a+b) &\leq (a+b)\\
&\leq 10,\\
\end{align}$$
and also
$$\begin{align}
(1-n)(c+d) &\leq (c+d)\\
&\leq 10.\\
\end{align}$$

But then I am lost on what to do next. Any complete help would be very much appreciated, I am pretty much a beginner in this craft. I hope this posting is not a duplication since I didn't see any similar problem from the prompts. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend not getting bogged down in the details of each coordinate of a vector in $\Bbb R^2$.  Instead, just let $x, y \in A$ (so they're vectors).  This has the advantage of being able to easily extend to $\Bbb R^n$, rather than just $\Bbb R^2$.

We can rewrite $A$ as $A=\{x : x^\top 1 < 10\}$, where $1$ represents the vector of all ones.  Now we aim to show, for any $t\in [0, 1]$, we have:

$$ x t + y(1-t) \in A $$

Then: 
\begin{align}
(x t + y(1-t))^\top 1 &= (x t)^\top 1 + (y(1-t))^\top 1\\
&=t(x^\top 1) + (1-t)(y^\top 1) \\
&< t(10) + (1-t)(10) \\
&< 10
\end{align}

Thus, we have $xt + y(1-t)\in A$ for any $x, y \in A$ and $t\in [0, 1]$.  Therefore, the set $A$ is convex, as was to be shown.

Comment: Thank you! Please give me some times to digest your posting, but for the time being I just wanted to express my gratitude. In the meantime, what does the superscript "T" and "1" mean as in the $x^T 1$? Is there any elementary way of saying it? I am totally new in this trade. Thanks again for your quick response.

Comment: @A.Magnus The superscript "T" ($^\top$) is a "transpose operator, and I'm using $1$ to represent a vector of all ones (e.g. $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ for the two-dimensional case).  With these definitions, $x^\top 1$ is just $x_1 + x_2$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the two components of $x$.

Comment: Sorry, one more question if you donot mind: How do you translate $(xt + y(1-t))^T$? Thanks again.